error message 'Delete `␍`eslintprettier/prettier' in nest js project
code prettier code
prettierrc
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all"
}


eslintc.js
    module.exports = {
      parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
      parserOptions: {
    project: 'tsconfig.json',
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'],
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  root: true,
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': ['error', { "singleQuote": true, "parser": "flow" }],
    '@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
  },
  env: {
    node: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js'],
};


i want to resolve the error showing, error message 'Delete ␍eslintprettier/prettier' in nest js project , i recently started using nest for my backend project and i was getting so many errors from code prettier and eslint idk how to resolve it

By the way this question has been already answered
Link: Why do I keep getting "[eslint] Delete `CR` [prettier/prettier]"?
    rules: {
     'prettier/prettier': [
      'error',
      {
        endOfLine: 'auto',
      },
       ],
    'prettier/prettier': ['error', { "singleQuote": true, "parser": "flow" }],
    '@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
  },
  env: {
    node: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js'],
};

